# How to use Android permission which is defined in an app which will get installed after my app

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm getting Security Exception when I try to use permission in my app which is actually defined using "permission" tag in a different app which will get installed after my app.

Please let me know how to avoid this?

Q.1) Is there a way to make sure my app will get installed only after other app so that permission will be granted as expected?

Q.2) Is there any other way to fix this issue.

One work around I thought of is to define that permission in my app as well. In that way I'll have both "permission" and "use-permission" tag for the same permission string in my manifest file. Is this ok to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make sure my app will get installed only after other app so that permission will be granted as expected?

Unfortunately, no.

> Is there any other way to fix this issue.

Let's say that App A is the one defining the permission and App B is the one using the permission. If the user installs App B before App A, you will need to ask the user to uninstall App B and reinstall it after installing App A.

> One work around I thought of is to define that permission in my app as well. In that way I'll have both "permission" and "use-permission" tag for the same permission string in my manifest file. Is this ok to do like this?

I suspect that the second app to try to declare the permission will fail to install due to the permission name collision, but I have not tried this and therefore cannot be certain.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare: Thanks for the reply.

But I would like to get a solution where I don't want to uninstall and reinstall previous app.

Anyway I tried installing 2 apps with same permission declared, and both of the apps got installed fine, didn't get any permission name collision.

So for now defining same permission in 2 different apps seems to be working solution for me !!